# I get 2 texts from xpath, how can I get only 1 text value?

Tags: html, xpath

```
<span class="material-icons topMenuPimIcons">ohrm_pim</span>Personal Details</a></li>
```

From the above HTML, I am trying to get text for 'Personal details', so I have created an XPath as

```
//span[text()='Personal Details']
```

And I have used above xpath and used get text method then in result I see the text is received as "ohrm_pim PersonalDetails

> java.lang.AssertionError: expected [Personal Details] but found [ohrm_pimPersonal Details]

Answer (score 1):

To get the text `Personal details`, you can use the following XPath-1.0 expression:

```
//span[text()='ohrm_pim']/following::text()[1]
```

And BTW: I had to add opening tags `<li><a>` to make your markup *well-formed*.

Answer (score 0):

To complete @zx485's answer, this should work too :

```
//span[.="ohrm_pim"]/../text()
```